# \big{|} fails with "Invalid Delimiter Type 'ordgroup' in VSCode .ipynb .md cell

Tags: rendering

One particular line fails to render in an .ipynb (rendered in VSCode).

```
$$
\lambda_N(x)  = \sum_{i=0}^N\big{|}\ell_i(x)\big{|}
$$
```

This is the culprit:

```
$\big{|}$
```

Error is:

> ParseError: KaTeX parse error: Invalid delimiter type 'ordgroup' at position 5: \big{|}

As the rest of the notebook renders fine, I am not sure whether the error is a TeX error or an issue with VSCode's .ipynb rendering engine.

What might be the problem?

EDIT: For context, much academic work is shared in the form of iPython Notebooks (.ipynb) which can contain code and/or markdown cells. In markdown cells we're able to include math equations like `$x^2 + y^2 = 1$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I paste the lne of code in a short LaTeX template and compile, I get no errors.

Comment: Given that adding the first code you provide to a simple sample document and it compiles just fine, you will need to provide more information for example a full minimal example. Additionally probably none of us knows what `.ipynb` refers to, so please elaborate.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This works flawlessly in plain TeX and in LaTeX (where, though, `$$` is not the best choice, but it's irrelevant). So the problem is in some rendering engine which is *not* TeX, which makes the question off-topic, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure whether the error is a TeX error or an issue with VSCode's .ipynb rendering engine

As others have already pointed out, your code snippet actually compiles correctly when compiled with a proper TeX engine. Presumably, this is because -- as @egreg has noted in a comment -- `\big|` and `\big{|}` do exactly the same thing.

For the equation at hand, then, I can only surmise that the problem is with your particular rendering engine rather than with LaTeX itself. I assume that you are aware that some programs process code whose syntax closely resembles LaTeX syntax but employ a non-TeX engine, such as MathJax.

At any rate, you can't go wrong if you replace

```
\lambda_N(x) = \sum_{i=0}^N\big{|}\ell_i(x)\big{|}
```

with

```
\lambda_N(x) = \sum_{i=0}^N \bigl| \ell_i(x) \bigr|
```

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect. In plain TeX and LaTeX, `\big|` and `\big{|}` do exactly the same thing and no, the braces don't change the status, because they are removed as soon as the argument to `\big` is scanned.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've updated my answer accordingly.